# Using lsof to get a list of file names

Tags: unix, command-line

**EDIT 1**

I'm having problems using the arguments given. Maybe it is the way I'm passing my arguments through NSTask? Any suggestions as to how I can do this?

```
NSTask *file_Task = [NSTask new];
[file_Task setLaunchPath:@"/usr/sbin/lsof"];
[file_Task setArguments:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"+p", the_Pid, nil]];
```

---

Good Afternoon Fellow Coders....

I'm using the following command:

```
lsof +p 13812
```

to get the list of a files accessed by a process. The thing is it is giving me a lot of additional information that I don't want such as TYPE, DEVICE, etc.

Is there an argument that I can add to the above command so that I get **ONLY** the **NAME**?

Thank you, thank you thank you! :)

Eric

Comment: Do you also 'only' want the files that the process has open? 'lsof' will return an entry for all open file descriptors (files, sockets, ttys, etc.) as well as the current working directory, shared libraries.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use:

```
lsof -Fn +p 12345
```

This will output a list of lines, with the first being `p` followed by the process ID,
and all following lines consisting of `n` followed by the file name.

If you'd like to quickly preprocess this, you can do something similar to the following:

```
lsof -Fn +p 12345 | tail -n +2 | cut -c2-
```

See the [`lsof` man page](http://www.manpagez.com/man/8/lsof/) for more information, specifically under the `OUTPUT FOR OTHER PROGRAMS` heading.

Comment: FYI, at least in recent versions of `lsof`, your example (`lsof -Fn +p 12345`) will output file descriptor lines as well.

Answer (score 5):

try:

```
lsof | tr -s ' ' | cut -d' ' -f9
```

Comment: This will also print the header as well, unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

lsof +p 9174 | awk '{ print $9 }'

Comment: Consider spaces in file names.

Answer (score 1):

Listing the currently playing song (nfs file, accessed by user mpd):

```
$ sudo lsof -N -a -u mpd -Fn | 
   sed '/n/!d; s/^n//'
/R/audio/[...] Jay-Jay Johanson , So Tell The Girls That I Am Back.mp3
```

The sed part deletes any lines not starting with n and removes n in the final output.